# SQL Server convert string mm/dd/yyyy HH:mi:ss +ZH:ZM to DateTime with TZ

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

One of Microsoft's own systems (Dynamics365 outbound marketing to Azure Data Lake Storage) delivers dates in string format thus:
02/20/2023 13:37:24 +00:00

What's the best way to convert this into a DateTime with time zone in SQL Server?

I tried some date and time styles like

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(DateTime, '02/20/2023 13:37:24 +00:00', 122)

SELECT CONVERT(DateTime, '02/20/2023 13:37:24 +00:00', 111)
```

but just got

> SQL Error [241] [S0001]: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: If you check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#date-and-time-styles) you'll note that the neither of the style you have used, `122` (Not listed) and `111` (`yyyy/mm/dd`), are not the style of your data; which is `MM/dd/yyyy`. Use the *correct* style code `CONVERT` works fine. Though I would suggest using a `datetimeoffset(0)` for the data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What's the best way to convert this into a DateTime with time zone in SQL Server?

Data type DateTime does not have any time zone, so "DateTime with time zone" is not an option.

Your string does not fit for DATETIME but seems like DATETIMEOFFSET data type, which stores data like datetime2 and time zone in addition.

```
declare @DTO DATETIMEOFFSET(0) = CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET(7), '02/20/2023 13:37:24 +00:00', 101)
SELECT @DTO
-- You can now CONVERT the DATETIMEOFFSET into DATETIME and lose the OFFSET value
SELECT CONVERT (DATETIME, @DTO)
-- Or you can use the function SWITCHOFFSET to convert the time to any other specific time zone like Israel time (+02:00)
SELECT SWITCHOFFSET (@DTO, '+02:00')
```